# Why does echo 0.0000001 return an error?

Tags: php, string, variables, numbers, decimal

Why does something as simple as this return error ?

```
echo 0.00000001;
```

`1.0E-8`

And this works OK:

```
echo number_format(0.00000001, 8);
```

`0.00000001`

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: looks like scientific notation